# Trying to run script as local user on remote machine via invoke-command with domain-admin

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to run scripts on a remote machine with a local user. Optimally a user of choice but it could also be the user thats currently logged in on the machine.

Here comes the tricky part .. I HAVE to use the domain admin to establish the session via invoke-command.. local users are blocked out of remote access ... but my script NEEDS to run in the local user context:

The following is one amongst many things i tried, but they all follow a similar principle:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $adminCred  -ScriptBlock{

    Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted

    [string]$userName = 'xxxxx'
    [string]$userPassword = 'yyyyy'
    [securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    [pscredential]$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secStringPassword)

    start-process powershell -ArgumentList "$powershellCode" -Credential $credObject -wait -WorkingDirectory $env:windir
}
```

I have tried numerous ways of passing and creating the credentials of the local users.. i have played around with all the parameters for start-process and invoke-command and I've tested the same with various forms of using PSsessions, but the resulting error is always:

```
This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Interestingly the whole command block within the invoke-command scriptblock works just fine if I run it locally.. no matter what user im logged on with.

I never have issues with invoke-command or start-process.. I just seem to get issues with this combination.

Any Ideas why this happens or workarounds?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the official [remote troubleshooting documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.2)?  In particular, as this is a local account, you may need to add the remote host to your local list of [trusted hosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.2#how-to-connect-remotely-from-a-workgroup-based-computer).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I went through the whole documentation and all is set up correctly already.. invoke-command has always worked.. and the command within the scriptblock works fine locally. I tried with different accounts as well (logged in and not logged in). I can only imagine there is an issue with using credentials within the session that are different from the ones being used to open the session.